# If the projections of $OA$ and $OB$ on the plane $z=0$ make angles $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$,respectively,with the $x-$axis

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

$OA,OB,OC,$ with $O$ as origin, are three mutually perpendicular lines whose direction cosines are $l_1,m_1,n_1;l_2,m_2,n_2$ and $l_3,m_3,n_3$ respectively. If the projections of $OA$ and $OB$ on the plane $z=0$ make angles $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, respectively, with the $X-$axis, prove that $\tan(\phi_1-\phi_2)=\pm\dfrac{n_3}{n_1n_2}$

---

I could not solve this question,the answer given in my book seems erroneous.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in your book is all right, it just skips the part that you were asking about earlier, I see you have edited that out. Still I'm just answering that part.

I assume that you know something about matrices. Even if you don't, just read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) wiki on orthogonal matrices.

The given conditions in your question are sufficient to show that the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
l_1&m_1&n_1\\l_2&m_2&n_2\\l_3&m_3&n_3
\end{pmatrix}$$ is an orthogonal matrix. It should be obvious now that $n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2=1$

Comment: I completely understood the concept and orthogonal matrices,thank you very much for your brilliant insight.@G-man